# How to close several windows with one mapping?

Tags: vim-windows

I use `CTRL-W c` to close current window.
I expected that `5 CTRL-W c` close 5 windows in row, but it's not. Now I just type `CTRL-W c` 5 times.

What is correct way to do it and why it don't work as I expected?

Comment: In case you want to close all window, _except_ the current window, then do `:only` or `<c-w>o`. See `:h :only`

Comment: Also, `ZZ` and any of the other quit/exit mechanisms close a window (unless it’s the last window, and then they quit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, giving a count to the command doesn't work as you expected because the doc ([`:h CTRL-W_c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_c)) says:

```
Without {count}: Close the current window.  If {count} is
given close the {count} window.
```

Now if you want to create a mapping calling `<C-w>c` N times you could add this to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F1> :<C-u>for i in range(v:count1) \| close \| endfor<CR>
```

Replace `<F1>` by the key you want to use in your mapping. What is line does is the following:

```
:                           Go to command line mode
<C-u>                       Remove the range automatically added to the command line
for i in range(v:count1)    Create a loop from 0 to the count you gave to the mapping (or 1 if you didn't gave a count)
close                       Close the current window
endfor                      End of the loop
<CR>                        Validate the command
```

Now you can press `<F1>` to close the current window and `4<F1>` to close the current window and the 3 next current windows.

You can read the following related help topics:

- [`:h c_CTRL-U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U)
- [`:h range()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#range%28%29)
- [`:h v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3acount1)
- [`:h :close`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3aclose)

Comment: The correct help item should be `:h c_CTRL-U` instead... `:h CTRL-U` is about page up in normal mode...